# Why do two empty strings compare as not equal?

Tags: string, bash, string-comparison

```
my@comp:~/wtfdir$ cat wtf.sh
str1=$(echo "")
str2=$(echo "")

if [ $str1 != $str2 ]; then
  echo "WTF?!?!"
fi
my@comp:~/wtfdir$ ./wtf.sh
WTF?!?!
my@comp:~/wtfdir$
```

WTF is going on here?!

How I wrote the above code: Googling "bash compare strings" brought me to [this website](https://linuxhint.com/compare_strings_bash/) which says:

> You can check the equality and inequality of two strings in bash by using if statement. “==” is used to check equality and “!=” is used to check inequality of the strings.

Yet I'm getting the above?

What am I not understanding? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quotes matter. Run `[ "$str1" != "$str2" ]`

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `[` isn't special syntax, it's just a command; its arguments go through the same expansion phases as every other command. If `ls $empty` runs just `ls` with no arguments, then `[ $empty != $empty ]` just runs `[ != ]`. (The special-syntax alternative to `test` is `[[`, and it doesn't have the problem you're asking about here).

Comment: `str1=` is sufficient to assign an empty value to `str1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You aren't running a comparison at all, because you aren't using quotes where they're mandatory. See the warning from http://shellcheck.net/ about unquoted expansions at [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086).

If both string are empty, then:

```
[ $str1 != $str2 ]
```

...evaluates to...

```
[ != ]
```

...which is a test for whether the string `!=` is nonempty, which is true. Change your code to:

```
[ "$str1" != "$str2" ]
```

...and the exact values of those strings will actually be passed through to [the `[` command](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest).

---

Another alternative is using `[[`; as described in [BashFAQ #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) and the [conditional expression page on the bash-hackers' wiki](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression), this is extended shell syntax (in ksh, bash, and other common shells extending the POSIX sh standard) which suppresses the string-splitting behavior that's tripping you up:

```
[[ $str1 != "$str2" ]]
```

...requires quotes only on the right-hand side, and even those aren't needed for the empty-string case, but to prevent that right-hand side from being treated as a glob (causing the comparison to always reflect a match if `str2='*'`).